# Phoenix API: How do I test a POST / create when I don't know the ID of the new resource?

Tags: testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I have an a POST /api/v1/users endpoint for creating a user. This is my failing test for it:

```
test "success" do
  user_params = %{
    user: %{
      email: "eric@spaghetti.com",
      image_url: "https://www.google.com/images/spaghetti",
    }
  }

  conn = build_conn(:post, "/api/v1/users", user_params)
  response = Router.call(conn, @opts)
  assert response.status == 201
  assert Repo.get_by(User, %{email: user_params.user.email})
  assert response.resp_body == %{
    id: "how would I know this??", #<---------this would fail since I have no way of knowing what this value would be
    email: user.email,
    image_url: user.image_url,
  } |> Poison.encode!
end
```

My endpoint returns 3 fields: email, image_url, and id. I am currently unable to get this test to pass because there's no way I can tell what the ID of the newly created resource will be. Is there a better way to test this?

Comment: i'm not familiar with phoenix and ecto but isn't there such functionality to return the last inserted row id? i bet there is one.

Comment: is it not a thing? wouldn't it be useful information for the newly logged in client to know its ID so it can use it to make future requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally skip checking for the exact value `id` in such cases, instead checking only if it exists:

```
%{email: email, image_url: image_url} = user

assert %{
  "id" => _,
  "email" => ^email,
  "image_url" => ^image_url,
} = Poison.decode!(response.resp_body)
```

You can also assert that `id` is an integer:

```
assert %{
  "id" => id,
  "email" => ^email,
  "image_url" => ^image_url,
} = Poison.decode!(response.resp_body)
assert is_integer(id)
```

Comment: it looks like this syntax isn't allowed? `cannot invoke remote function user.email/0 inside match`

Comment: Oops, sorry, I forgot about that. Let me think of another way. I used to use this syntax for constant strings on the LHS, which works.

Comment: If you can store `email` and `image_url` in a variable earlier, you can use the pin operator: `assert %{"email" => ^email, "image_url" => ^image_url} = ...`.